# API Gateway Lambda request authorizer error when request has body

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, lambda-authorizer

I am experiencing a weird issue with my Lambda request authorizer for this API gateway endpoint where when the request has a body, I get this error:

```json
{
  "errorType": "UnprocessableEntityError",
  "errorMessage": "Invalid or malformed JSON was provided",
  "trace": [
    "UnprocessableEntityError: Invalid or malformed JSON was provided",
    "    at Object.createError (/var/task/node_modules/@middy/util/index.cjs:212:12)",
    "    at httpJsonBodyParserMiddlewareBefore (/var/task/node_modules/@middy/http-json-body-parser/index.cjs:25:42)",
    "    at runMiddlewares (/var/task/node_modules/@middy/core/index.cjs:123:27)",
    "    at runRequest (/var/task/node_modules/@middy/core/index.cjs:83:15)",
    "    at Runtime.middy1 [as handler] (/var/task/node_modules/@middy/core/index.cjs:37:16)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnceNonStreaming (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:73:25)"
  ]
}
```

If I remove the body from the request, the authorizer works correctly, but of course the endpoint does not function as expected because there is no data passed to it. Conversely, if I remove the authorizer the request works as expected but is not protected by an authorizer.

The authorizer has a `Payload Format Version` of `2.0`, and a `Response Format` of `Simple`.

The request body I'm trying to send is a simple 3 key-value JSON object like:

```json
{
   "key1": "value1",
   "key2": "value2",
   "key3": "value3"
}
```

The authorizer configuration 512 MB memory and storage with a 30 second timeout.

Does anyone know how I might be able to allow for my request to have a body, but the authorizer not throw this error?

Comment: What does your configuration look like, what is the request body exactly?

Comment: @luk2302 have updated the question with that information

Comment: Just to confirm, the error is raised before lambda is even executed? How/what are you returning from your authorizer function?

Comment: @BenFreiberg Correct, the lambda that handles the endpoint never gets invoked. The authorizer lambda does get invoked but before it even executes the first line of code in the handler function it gives the above error. Depending on whether or not the authorizer grants authorization, it returns a JSON object with { isAuthorized: true/false }

Comment: @jhf2 you are using middy, have you looked at https://github.com/middyjs/middy/issues/653

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue. I removed `middyfy` from the export in the function and that solved things. I guess middy should not be used for authorizers.

Comment: did you find any other solutions?